# nginx upload module regexp

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx, upload, php5-fpm

Добрый день. 
Пытаюсь сконфигурить [nginx upload module](http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.ru.html)

Пример ссылки, которая должна обрабатываться модулем:

```
http://server.com/?r=upload/api&uuid=0la4fzVZUMUulOliVcleXY0Kn9nmJGAy&sid=6eo5bhrslh3lggb8kmu8lgk781
```

Конфиг nginx:

```
    server {
        listen      *:80;
        server_name server.com;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        # Define root
            root /path/to/root;
        set     $fs_webroot "/path/to/root";
        index   index.php;
        # robots.txt
        location = /robots.txt {
            alias $fs_webroot/deny.robots.txt;
        }

    # Upload form should be submitted to this location
            location ~ "^/\?r=upload/api(.*)" {
                    client_max_body_size 500M;

                    # Pass altered request body to this location
                    upload_pass @php_fpm;

                    # Resumable upload
                    upload_resumable on;
                    upload_state_store /upload_path/states;
                    # Store files to this directory
                    upload_store /upload_path;

                    # Set specified fields in request body
                    upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_name" $upload_file_name;
                    upload_set_form_field "${upload_field_name}_path" $upload_tmp_path;
                    upload_pass_args on;
                    # Cleanup
                    upload_cleanup 400 401 403 404 499 500-505;

                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

            }

    # Domain root
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~\.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/path_to_sock.sock;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $fs_webroot/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_script_name;

        add_header Pragma no-cache;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache,must-revalidate;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

        location @php_fpm {
                fastcgi_pass   unix:/path_to_sock.sock;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fs_webroot/$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD  $request_method;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_script_name;
        add_header Pragma no-cache;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache,must-revalidate;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

}
```

В логе на POST-запросы получаю "200". Но явно вижу что запрос обрабатывается НЕ модулем.
Подозреваю, что проблема в кривых регулярках.

Помогите! :)
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Для работы с get параметрами, кажется, есть переменная `$args`, параметры в location не прописать.

Comment: тут POST, не GET

Comment: Вот зачем придумывать себе сложности что бы потом из пытаться героически преодолеть? Почему нельзя сделать адрес вида `http://server.com/upload/?uuid=xxx`?

Comment: `$request_body, эта переменная содержит тело запроса. Значение переменной появляется в location’ах, обрабатываемых директивами proxy_pass и fastcgi_pass.`

Comment: @NickKatsy всё что в урле после знака вопроса это GET-параметры. И при этом совершенно неважно что у вас POST-запрос.